# Spell that allows a target to find food and water easily while in the wild

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, druid

I'm trying to create a cool background for my character in a friend's campaign, and he approved of what I wrote, but was curious if I could find some actual mechanics that I could the fluff into.

The main thing that he would like me to try and translate is the item that my dragon parents created for me. It is a pair of silver cross earrings that enabled me (in a human form) to survive in the wild for 60 some years, and I've been able to find spells that I could work in to cover every aspect of survival, save one: food and water.

So, this begs the question: is there a spell (preferably druidic) that provides the target to be able to easily find food and water while in the wild (and spell duration does not matter, because he fluffed why the spells lasted so long)?

Comment: So two questions: would simply giving a bonus to survival work? Could it give daily spell like ability castings? If so I could answer.

Comment: Daily spell-like-ability castings would work fine, and bonus to survival would work, but if possible he would prefer a spell or spell-like.

Answer (score 4):

Does the item *provide* food and water? Or help you *find* it? If the latter, I'd have it give a competence bonus to survival checks.

The cost for that is the [bonus squared X 100](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values), so a +5 to Survival would be 2,500 GP.

Note that it would be reasonable to provide a discount if this only affects your ability to find food/water and not your ability to track.

If you're looking for a spell (rather than an item ability), in addition to the ones suggested by Dan B, I'll suggest [guidance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/guidance) (Druid 0) which gives you a +1 bonus to Survival (or any other skill), and [abstemiousness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/abstemiousness) (Druid 1), which

> magically enhances a handful of simple food, imbuing it with enough nutrition to satisfy a Medium or smaller creature for a full day. The spell does not create food, and thus will not alone prevent someone from starving, but it can extend even limited reserves for lengthy periods.

Guidance seems most like the flavor you're looking for...except that the effect is likely too small. The advantage of Abstemiousness over Goodberry is that it doesn't tie you to berries only.

Note that there's also [Bloodhound](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bloodhound) which gives you scent, and +4 to track with Survival...but as written it provides no benefit to finding food in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [create water](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/createWater.html) (Druid 0) and [goodberry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/goodberry) (Druid 1).  Goodberry technically requires that you find some berries but it just takes a few.

There's also the [ring of sustenance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sustenance) which costs 2500gp and stops you from needing food.

Comment: The spell I was thinking of was something you could cast on an animal and then the animal would be able to find food, water, and shelter; but I can't remember what the name off the spell is.

Comment: @Cyberson Ah.  Sorry, I don't know of any spell like that.

Comment: In addition to the spoon, there is also the Ring of Who Needs Food Anyway - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sustenance

Answer (score 1):

### *Commune with Nature*

When it comes to learning about your local environment, the go-to nature spell is *[Commune with Nature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/commune-with-nature)*. A druid, ranger, or shaman can cast this spell to learn about potential resources in the surrounding area, such as vegetation, water, and animals (for hunting). The caster will "instantly gain knowledge of as many as three facts", so the information is generally correct. The spell has a very wide area of effect, and then the knowledge is permanent.

**Backup choices:**

***[Divination](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/divination)*** is a divine spell that is somewhat similar to *Commune with Nature*. It can provide helpful advice to questions like "Where can I find clean water and food?"  It's not on the druid spell list, although a witch can cast it. This spell can be incredible in some situations. However, the information granted by the spell is not necessarily straightforward or true, so maybe it's not the most reliable method for surviving in the wild.

***[Grove of Respite](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/grove-of-respite)*** is a useful way for a druid to create some water and edible vegetation for a brief period of time. Maybe if it was used to create a magic item, then the item helps the user locate these things in the wilderness.  I recommend this spell over *[Oasis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/oasis)*, which is limited to water only.

There is also ***[Create Food and Water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-food-and-water)***, another non-druid spell.  As the name suggests, it creates edible food and drinkable water for the caster.  This is the spell that is used in a [Ring of Sustenance.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sustenance)

Answer (score 0):

Besides what have already been mentioned, there is [Allfood](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/allfood), a 2nd level Ranger spell that turns anything to (tasteless and gooey) food.

Comment: Now I have mental images in my head of a party eating their way through a dungeon wall.

Answer (score 0):

The Pathfinder spell (Druid 0th/Ranger 1st) "divining rod" from 1001 spells Rite Publishing may be a very good reference.